# What to put as launcher:ClassName for launcher favorite

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

My client wants to put the app I developed to be in their launcher favorite and they are asking for the package name and class name of the launcher.
Package name is quite straightforward, but ClassName isn't since if I look into the manifest the class name is preceeded by a hash like this: md599e473470f20dc18f556aff51bcfbcb1.LaunchScreen

So what is the class name I have to use for launcher favorite, the whole thing or only the class name LaunchScreen?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(Congrats on getting into their favorites, should you provide a Play link ;-)

As you say, the package name is easy, it is the defined in the manifest as a `package` attribute of the `manifest` element:

```
<manifest .... package="com.sushihangover.playscriptstarling2" ...>
```

The launcher class name is the class that is tagged within the `Activity` C# class attribute, *"MainLauncher = true"*

In turn, this creates the `activity` attribute fragment within the manifest:

```
<activity android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="PlayScriptStarling2" android:name="md5d2519388ea1895e3e3594794d2e0c4ce.MainActivity">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Your class name is the full `android:name` attribute since it does NOT begin with a period. This is a generated unique subclass identifier, thus in my example this is the full class name:

```
md5d2519388ea1895e3e3594794d2e0c4ce.MainActivity
```

While most people will never see this class ID, I *highly* recommend you override this generate class identifier and use the dot class notation that includes your package name.

Normally, this is done by providing a name using the `android:name` that BEGINS with a period (this is standard Android class naming 101 ;-) but Xamarin currently does **not** support Android shorthand-style class names beginning w/ a dot so you need to use the fully qualified package name with your class ID name.

So the Main Activity attribute becomes:

```
[Activity(Label = "PlayScriptStarling2", Name = "com.sushihangover.playscriptstarling2.MyBigBadGameEveryOneShouldPlay", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
```

And the generated manifest becomes:

```
<activity android:icon="@mipmap/icon" android:label="PlayScriptStarling2" android:name="com.sushihangover.playscriptstarling2.MyBigBadGameEveryOneShouldPlay">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And my launcher class name becomes:

```
com.sushihangover.playscriptstarling2.MyBigBadGameEveryOneShouldPlay
```

*Android Docs:*

> Declaring class names
>
> Many elements correspond to Java objects, including elements for the application itself (the  element) and its principal components — activities (), services (), broadcast receivers (), and content providers ().
>
> If you define a subclass, as you almost always would for the component classes (Activity, Service, BroadcastReceiver, and ContentProvider), the subclass is declared through a name attribute. The name must include the full package designation. For example, an Service subclass might be declared as follows:

```
<manifest . . . >
    <application . . . >
        <service android:name="com.example.project.SecretService" . . . >
            . . .
        </service>
        . . .
    </application>
</manifest>
```

> However, as a shorthand, if the first character of the string is a period, the string is appended to the application's package name (as specified by the  element's package attribute).

The following assignment is the same as the one above:

```
<manifest package="com.example.project" . . . >
    <application . . . >
        <service android:name=".SecretService" . . . >
            . . .
        </service>
        . . .
    </application>
</manifest>
```

> When starting a component, Android creates an instance of the named subclass. If a subclass isn't specified, it creates an instance of the base class.

Ref: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml/#Intent_Actions_and_Features

Comment: Thanks SO much for your complete answer!

Comment: NP, and congrats again

Comment: Well its the client who has the prestige, not me. Its for this summer's games in brasil, if you know what I mean. And I just modified the beginning of my post because I don't even know if I am allowed to talk about it... thanks again for your quick answer!